# 2 sequence query update in 1 function Model Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, controller

I have this query update that needs 2 sequence to complete the job. It's like this :

Model:

```
$result = DB::statement( DB::raw("SET @a:=0;") );
$numbering = DB::update(DB::raw(UPDATE table SET number:= @a+1, table_number = number+1 ));

return $numbering;
```

if i executed that function, only the **number** column is filled with value ***@a+1*** , but the **table_number** column is still blank. I have to run the function twice in controller to get table_number column filled with the values **number+1**

Answer (score 0):

The number column isn't yet set at the time of the first update so use

```
UPDATE table SET number:= @a+1, table_number = @a+2
```

Comment: the value is not fixed, i want to make to make the value of the table_number can be whatever from number column. not +2

Comment: As long as the number column is not yet set, you can't  update  with it's unset value, you can however work with the value with which you want to use to set it

Comment: what im asking is is there any way to do the 2 query in one laravel model function instead of running 2 method in laravel controller